# Permission of Unix/Linux systems

Tags: linux, unix, permissions

So I am currently learning the command line of Linux in my software design class, and I have come across the permission sections of files.

It is fairly self-explanatory to me about the concept of rwx being read, write, and excecutable.

However, in the section of explaining directory permissions, I came across the convention rwxr.

How is rwx different from rwxr?

The source of the original article is:
http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0090.php

Comment: Did you read that article you linked? It explains the answer to your question with a nice diagram.  It explains how the permissions correspond with octal values, and shows how to use `chmod`.  There are three sets of characters, one for the file owner, group owner, and all other users. You are mixing two of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the different ... user / group / world
this are the 3 block.